# php - datetimezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm using functions with the datetime object that require a datetimezone object as an argument. I see a list of timezones here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

but there's not things like 'est'. How could I create a 'datetimezone' object from EST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('EST');
```

Comment: Not to be confused with `$tz = new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern');` which takes into account daylight savings time in the US incase anyone else stumbled across this and is actually looking for "US/Eastern" timezone.

Answer (score 2):

In http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php you can find in the OTHER section the EST there.

To create one use **date_default_timezone_set('EST');**

To make sure you have it do **echo date_default_timezone_get();**

Answer (score 1):

A very verbose loop.  The construct function for the DateTime class isn't working properly for me but this works.

```
$date = "2011/03/20";
$date = explode("/", $date);

$time = "07:16:17";
$time = explode(":", $time);

$tz_string = "America/Los_Angeles"; // Use one from list of TZ names http://us2.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$tz_object = new DateTimeZone($tz_string);

$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
$datetime->setDate($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
$datetime->setTime($time[0], $time[1], $time[2]);

print $datetime->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of that some TimeZone abbreviations like `EST` are not unique. See http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/.

The usage of `EST` is not recommended, see 
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php.

Use for example `America/New_York` instead.